# The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

Hi there I am developing a simple auto mailing server where the receiver gets an email with some content and a button to click which composes an email for the receiver to reply to a specific email address.

This is my code and I am getting an error on line I described in a comment

```
exports.sendOrderCompletionEmail = functions.firestore.document('/service-requests/{req_id}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const req = context.params.req_id;
            
        const refresh = change.after.data();
        const sts = refresh.status;
        //console.log("Yes recieved" + sts);
        if (sts === "completed") {
            const em = refresh.email;
            const nm = refresh.name;

            let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'gmail',
                secure: false,
                port: 25,
                auth: {
                    user: process.env.EMAIL_ID,
                    pass: process.env.PASS_EM
                },
                tls: {
                    rejectUnauthorized: false
                }
            });
    
            let HelperOptions = {
                from: '"AnyShott" <anyshott.noreply@gmail.com',
                to: `${em}`,
                subject: 'AnyShott Photoshoot Order Completed Successfully',
                html : `<img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anyshott.appspot.com/o/0.png?alt=media&token=c7ddddd2-156f-4a2c-a7ee-c7d12f95fb4a" width="200px"><br>
                        <b>Hello ${nm},</b><br>
                        <p>Congratulations, Your Photoshoot Order has been Successfully Completed.
                        Hope you liked the Photos and Flaunting on your Social Media. Looking forward to hearing from you. Give us your Feedback simply by Replying to this Email.</p>
                        <button style="padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;border-radius: 25px 50px 50px 50px;border: none;color: white;background-color:#F67001;cursor:pointer;" type="button" onclick="window.location = 'mailto:anyshott@gmail.com'">Click here to give feedback</button> <!--Getting error over here-->
                        <br>
                        <p>We would like to Thank you for your order.</p>
                        <p>Regards,</p>
                        <p>AnyShott.</p>
                        <p>Delivering Moments</p><img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anyshott.appspot.com/o/1f49d.png?alt=media&token=7e04e3d5-8728-4d93-b538-0b74c65ab8ec" width="50px">`
                
            };
    
            transporter.sendMail(HelperOptions, (error, info) => {
                if (error) {
                    return console.log(error);
                }
                console.log("The email was sent!");
                console.log(info);
            });
        }
                
    });
```

As the title says email is blocking my inline script.

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).

> Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src or style-src: nonce-source or hash-source specified

Consider me as a noob and please describe to me what's the problem and also explain what is this Policy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those errors look like they come from client code, but all you're showing here is backend Cloud Functions code.  It's not clear how they are related.

Comment: Yes its coming from console logs which I got from my gmail when I try to click the button. But I believe it's because of my server side code that I forgot to add some exception flags in my button to override CSP in gmail. As per I can understand from logs it's saying gmail's security policy is blocking my script for changing the page. That is inline script blocking. Again I say it's because of my server side code that I am forgetting something to add to override the CSP.

Comment: This may sound odd but try a different browser  and incognito window, I've seen several scenarios where that specific message is a transient error and it's solved within a few hours.